# file upload using fetch API in javaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, fetch, multipart

Hi I am trying to upload a tar file from so many days, but everytime I am failing. I am new to this JS, UI and https req/res domain.
My environment is: nodeJS, JavaScript for backend. ReactJS for frontend.
I need to upload tar file from my machine to remote server.

Here is my frontend code where I am making fetch request to upload a file.

```
export function postXCCDF () {
  let _headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json, application/xml, text/plain, text/html, *.*',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryyEmKNDsBKjB7QEqu'
  };

  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('type', 'file');
  formData.append('file', 'C:\\MyDrive\\rules.zip');

  let uri = '/rest/policy';

  const options = { method: 'POST', headers: _headers, body: formData };
  return fetch(`${_host}${urlPrefix}${uri}`, options)
    .then(processStatus)
    .then(response => response.json());

}
```

Here is my backend code , where I am expecting the tar file to receive.

```
router.post('/policy', function(req, res) {
    console.log('hey I reached here');
    console.log('hemant req',req.body.formData); // prints hemant req undefined
    // Dont know how to save it to some directory. ??? :(
});
```

My whole idea is to upload a tar file to a server located at remote location. I have tried lot many other ways, but nothing seems to help.

Comment: Please use https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15772861 to edit/update your answer to provide the text of any error messages you see in the browser devtools console and in the backend server logs. And look in the Network panel of devtools to see if the request is actually getting sent, and what the request headers are, and see what response is being received, and what the headers are

Answer (score 1):

The body-parser module only handles JSON and urlencoded form submissions, not multipart (which would be the case if you're uploading files).

For multipart, you'd need to use something like [connect-busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/connect-busboy) or [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) or [connect-multiparty](https://github.com/expressjs/connect-multiparty) (multiparty/formidable is what was originally used in the express bodyParser middleware).